# Can a popup window embedded in a dialog expand (in a clipable way) to the device window border?

Tags: android, dialog, popup

I have a popup window attached to a 'button' (well, a TextView really) in a dialog activity:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="com.MyActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
```

my_activity_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    etc...

</LinearLayout>
```

MyActivity:

```
PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(this);
popupWindow.setWidth(250);
popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TextView dropDownView = findViewById(R.id.dropDownView);
```

and finally in dropDownView onClickListener():

```
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(v, -5, 0);  //where v=dropDownView
```

which nicely displays a dropdown box below my TextView.  However, the popup window is clipped to the bounds of the dialog (i.e. the lower bound of the popup window ends at the edge of the dialog and scrolling is enabled).  I can set the following:

```
popupWindow.setClippingEnabled(false);
```

and this does indeed allow the drop down list to expand beyond the dialog, but unfortunately also the window.  Is there a way to allow the popup window to expand beyond the dialog but be bounded by the window (and thus provide scrolling when the popup is larger than the window)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally found a workaround for this issue:

```
int[] location = new int[2];
view.getLocationOnScreen(location); //get physical location in Px
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int screenHeightPx = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int maxHeight = screenHeightPx - location[1] - view.getHeight() - 20; 

PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(this);
....
popupWindow.setHeight(maxHeight);
popupWindow.setClippingEnabled(false);
```

They key here is to find the position of the popup window's anchor view on the screen. Subtract its y coordinate from the max height of the screen to get the distance from the top left of the view to the bottom of the screen.  From this I take away the height of the anchor view (to get the y coordinate of the bottom edge) and finally 20 more for padding (should probably convert that to DP first).